# HTML/CSS Absolute Position of Element on Split Screen Design

Tags: html, css, position, absolute

I am trying to center the disc in the middle of the page overlapping my left and right div. The way I have found to do it is using the below code however, the disc shoots off the page to the right when I do. Please can someone help me understand why as I have googled and watched YouTube videos and they say this is how you do it. It is even working in the YouTube video but not for me. I am really stuck.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  width: 50vw;
  display: relative;
  background-color: #abc;
}

.right {
  width: 50vw;
  background-color: #687;
}

.disc {
  width: 16em;
  height: 16em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: -8em;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="disc"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To position a child element, the parent element need to have a position attribute (position: relative; atleast) for its childs to inherit. That is why your .disc element went off to the right.

So simply add

```
position: relative;
```

to the parent elements, the .left and .right class

I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you - This has worked. I realised that I had display: relative and not position: relative. I went code blind! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want to position the disc in the middle horizontaly.

If that's the case, you can use the right property in conjunction with the CSS calc function to get the desired behavior, like this:

```
...
.disc {
    ...
    right: calc(50vw - 8em);
    ...  
}
...
```

Where `vw` stands for viewport width and `8em` is half of the disc width.

You can see the complete code [here](https://codepen.io/fferreira12/pen/ZEGKJyV).